# AngularJS ngModel input number as decimal

Tags: angularjs, input, numbers

I have an input field that binds to product price which has 2 decimal precisions:

```
<input type="number" name="price" step=".01" id="price" ng-model="product.price" min="0" max="1000000" required>
```

I then ng-submit this product and get response from the server, updated the product.price from what's echo'ed from server, but the above *price input* becomes empty, now from

```
console.log($scope.product.price)
```

I can tell that this value from server is a string now, but then even if I do the follows:

```
$scope.product.price = parseFloat(response.updatedModel.price).toFixed(2);
```

the *price input* is still empty.... how can I make this *price input* show that price value in 2 decimal precisions echo'ed from server?

Comment: try removing `.toFixed(2);`: `$scope.product.price = parseFloat(response.updatedModel.price);`

Comment: Yes, you're right about that! Thanks bro!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `input` requires the property to be a Number, but `toFixed` converts it to string.

Try removing `.toFixed(2);`:

`$scope.product.price = parseFloat(response.updatedModel.price);`

When working with model-view architecture, the model should not be concerned with how it's displayed, it's view's concern which is your input (`step=".01"`) in your case.